How to handle single file with typedoc?
I have a vue3 typescript project with vite, when i try using typedoc to generate docs, it not works well with the project.
I have tried a typedoc plugin called typedoc-plugin-vue, but it only works with definecomponent, not setup.
So for .vue file, i'd like to extract code inside <script> and save in a temporary .ts file, then using typedoc to generate its doc.
But how to generate doc for single file with typedoc? like
# {project}/src/App.vue
$ npx typedoc --entryPoints {project}/src/App.vue --out ./docs/src/App.md

Here's my origin typedoc config file
{
    "$schema": "https://typedoc.org/schema.json",
    "entryPoints": ["../src/App.vue"],
    "out": "./docs",
    "plugin": [
        "typedoc-plugin-vue",
        "typedoc-plugin-markdown"
    ]
}

And here's the project structure
# {project}
- public
- typedoc
  - docs
  - package.json
  - typedoc.json
- src
  - components
    - Title
      - Title.vue
      - type.ts
  - router
    - index.ts
    - type.ts
  - store
    - index.ts
    - type.ts
  - views
    - Home
      - Home.vue
      - type.ts
    - Config
      - Config.vue
      - type.ts
  - App.vue
  - main.ts
  - types.ts
- index.html
- tsconfig.json
- vite.config.ts
- package.json
-vite

